# Would iTunes convert lossless file to MP4/3 “automatically” under any circumstance?

Tags: windows, itunes

I ripped all my dad’s music for him from CD to lossless—FLAC or AIC I believe—in order to load it onto his iPod years ago.

He’s recently asked me to double check that his backups are working and the music directory is much smaller then I was expecting. I checked to see what was up, and the music is now a mix of 260+ VBR M4A.

I’m not sure if my memory is failing, or if iTunes would have converted the library for his iPhone or something?

Answer (score 0):

> I ripped all my dad’s music for him from CD to lossless—FLAC or AIC I
>   believe—in order to load it onto his iPod years ago.

iTunes does not support FLAC natively in any way. As [compiled in this list on Apple’s site](https://support.apple.com/kb/TA44475?locale=en_US) it breaks down like this:

iTunes 1.0 and later can import and play the following audio file types:

- AIFC
- audio CD
- MP3
- System 7 Sound (SND)
- uLaw (AU)
- WAV
- QDesign
- QuickTime audio (audio only movies)

iTunes 3 and later can also play these additional file types:
- Audible.com (format 2, 3, and 4)

iTunes 4 and later can also play these additional file types:

- AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
- MP4

Now that said, in my experience the “Convert higher bitrate songs to…” option that shows up when a device is attached to your system in iTunes can sometimes be reset if an iTunes update happens, an iTunes library rebuild happens or even if the device is reset and then one syncs with iTunes. The default setting is to convert higher bit rate songs to 128kbps, AAC. So this *might* be the cause of your dad’s issues, but without more specifics it’s hard to say?